# Bootstrap 3 - Where to place language toggler?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am converting my website to Bootstrap 3 and have a small 'language toggler' which I used to float on the right side. If you click on it the page 'magically' gets translated (it's just a redirect to another page)

[image]

The existing code, as shown below, is a bit annoying because the navbar-right element renders on two lines when there is not enough place. I haven't found any elegant solution for this, so I am considering moving the language toggler to another place on the page which won't be so affected by changes in size.

**Is there a best practice for this?**

Perhaps **move it to another place**, in the footer? I tried to see if there were any icons with flags, but no.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=active><a id="tab-home1" href="Homepage.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.magerman.com"><span>BLOG</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Services_Performance_Usability.html"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="References.html"><span>REFERENCES</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Partners.html"><span>PARTNERS</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ContactUs.html"><span>CONTACT
                        US</span></a></li>
            </ul>


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <div class="navbar-text">
                        <small>en | <a href="#" onclick="switchToGerman();return false;">de</a></small>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually language changing put in the dropdown. Try like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a id="tab-home1" href="Homepage.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://blog.magerman.com"><span>BLOG</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="Services_Performance_Usability.html"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="References.html"><span>REFERENCES</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="Partners.html"><span>PARTNERS</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUs.html"><span>CONTACT
                        US</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deutch</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```